# plupload - how to invoke a function when a user clicks an upload button?

Tags: events, plupload

I have a upload form that has 'AGREE TO TERMS' checkbox.

I want to check if a user checked it or not when the user clicks 'BROWSE' button.

i looked up http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html for events, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get a different approach:
create and destroy the plupload instance based on the state of the terms checkbox. Might not be what you were looking for, but it's in fact a better solution as the user never has access to the uploader until he agrees to the terms.

This also allows you to handle the click event in an alternate way by using the placeholder button you already have in your UI when the user has not yet agreed to the terms.